# Exporting query results to csv result in missing records - mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I run a query, it is said, 25307 rows returned; when I export the same query results to csv and check the # of rows there, it is 24K. What's the catch? Why are there missing records while exporting?

Comment: Maybe you can give a example which query you did run. i can't see any difference when i add INTO OUTFILE it gives the same result.

Comment: Interestingly, when I export as csv separated by a semicolon, I get my 25K in xls.